# Display value markers in Google Charts BarChart (JavaScript API)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to render a Google Charts BarChart with the value labels on, or next to the bars. By default, the values are being shown when the user hovers over a bar. I would like to show these values permanently in the graph.

As far as I can see, this was possible using the Image Charts API, but not with the JavaScript API. I am missing something?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the values in the legend (its how i got around the same problem)
Where you are setting the name of each column add the value next to it.

For example keeping track of stock in a warehouse:

```
var sold = 300;
var missing = 7;
var reserved = 5;
var available = 143;

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [' Available (' + available + ')', 'Missing (' + missing+ ')', 'Reserved (' + reserved+ ')', 'Sold (' + sold+ ')'],
    [available, missing, reserved, sold]
    ]);
```

Output:

- Available (143)
- Missing (7)
- Reserved (5)
- Sold (300)